# Ideas for data structure for implementing graph in c

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I want to implement a graph in C. I am confused on how should I store each node. I was first thinking of using a linked list but how can I store the next nodes connected to one node.

Any ideas what data structure should I use and how should I use it?

Comment: The optimal choice of structure depends on what operations you need to perform on the graph, and on how large and sparse it is.

Comment: For these types of questions, [Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/search?q=c+graph+structure), while StackOverflow is a pain in the ass.

Comment: Hope this can help http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/graph/linked/

Comment: DId you do *any* research? The wikipedia article on graph DS addresses this issue specifically: **[graph#representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29#Representations)**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(data_structure)#Representations

Answer (score 0):

There are some well known ways to do that.

One is to use a bidimensional array of size [n][n] where n is the number of nodes. And then set graph[a][b]= 1 if there is a link from a to b. This method is in general fast but uses a lot of memory, expecially if there are not so many links and many nodes.

Another way is to make a list (or an array, for the matter) of all nodes and set the content of everyone of them to point to a dynamic array or to a list of nodes it is linked to.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure that is helpful in case your graph is sparse is an [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)(linked list of linked lists) that is when you have few connections(edges) between the vertices.

If your graph is [dense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph) then use an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)(nxn) 2 dimensional array that is the case your vertices have lots of edges between them.